# How much ammo does an Xcom soldier have in a full magazine/clip?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

How much ammo does a basic Xcom soldier have in a full magazine/clip?
Abilities like Flush and Rapid Fire use 3 and 2 respectively but what is the full size and can it be upgraded?
Does shooting always use 1 ammo?

Comment: It varies by weapon I think - rifles seem to have 4 or 5, and heavy weapons only 3. Upgraded: yes, there's [a foundry project](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Ammo_Conservation) to give you lots more ammo a bit later in the game.

Comment: Yes, shooting always uses 1 ammo. Skills may use more than 1 (Suppression uses the most, if I recall correctly).

Comment: I think suppression and flush use the same amount; just hard to tell because they're skills for different classes.

Comment: The only weapon that doesn't use up ammo is the pistol. Doesn't matter if it's regular, laser or plasma.

Comment: "LMG offers significant less ammo before reloading. 3/6 rounds (before/after ammo conversation upgrade), compare to rifle's 4/8 rounds. This means LMG is less efficient at suppression (1/3) compare to support's rifle supression (2/4)."
From the Ufoaepedia - http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Weapons_%28EU2012%29

Heres the start of a break down
Rifle: 4(8)
Lmg: 3(6)
shotgun: ?
sniper rifle: ?
pistol: unl.

Flush: 3
rapid fire: 2 (only one shot used if first is a kill shot)
Supression: 3?

Answer (score 7):

Huwith said it, but here's the detailed answer:

Pistols can be fired infinitely without reloading.
Heavy weapons, from the LMG all the way up to the Heavy Plasma, have 3 shots worth of ammunition. This can be upgraded to 6 with the Ammo Conservation upgrade at the Foundry.
Shotguns, Sniper Rifles, and Assault Rifles all have 4 shots worth of ammunition, and can be upgraded to 8. The same once again holds for their upgraded versions.

Firing normally always uses 1 shot. Suppression uses 3. Any ability that fires twice uses 2, one per shot. Flush uses 3.